# Relation between continuity of $f$, $g$ and $f\circ g$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f$, $g$  be  functions  from  $[0,1]$ to  $[0,1]$  with  $f$  strictly  increasing . Then

$A.$ If  $f$  is  continuous  then  so  is  $f\circ g.$

$B.$ If $f$ and  $f\circ g$  are  continuous then  so  is  $g.$

$C.$ If  $g$  and $f\circ g$ are  continuous then  so  is  $f.$

Now  for  $A$ ,  I  can take  $g(x)=x$ and  $f$  any  discontinuous  function  thus  this  is  not  the  case.

If $g$  is  the  Dirichlet function  and  $f$  is  the  $0$  function or  $f(x)=1$ for  all $x\in [0,1]$  then  $B$  could  be cancelled  but  $f$  needed  to  be  strictly  increasing here  so  this  was  nonsense .

So  I  am  not  sure  about  the  last  two options.

Any  help  is  appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

B is true. Note that there exists a *continuous* function $h$ such that $h(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

C is false. Take $g$ to be a constant function, and construct a suitable counterexample from there.

---

**Proof that B is true:** Suppose that $f$ and $g$ satisfy the hypothesis of B.  Because $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, there exists a continuous function $h:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $h(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Now, since $f \circ g$ is continuous, it must be that $h \circ (f \circ g)$ is continuous.  However, note that for all $x$ we have $h(f(g(x))) = g(x)$, so that $h \circ f \circ g = g$.  Thus, $g$ must be continous.

**Proof that C is false:** Take $f(x)$ to be the function 
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x/3 & x \in [0,1/2)\\
2x/3 & x \in [1/2,1]
\end{cases}
$$
take $g(x) = 1$.  This $f$ and $g$ provide a counterexample to the claim given.

Comment: So  I  take  $g(x)=1$  and  $f$  the  Dirichlet  function . That  can  cancel  $C$.  But ,sorry, the  clue  for $B$  is  still  not  clear  to  me.

Comment: $f$ the Dirichlet function is not strictly increasing. Any discontinuous strictly increasing function will do, though. For B: note that $h\circ f \circ g$ must be continuous

Comment: Could  you  post  the  proof  in  detail  (hope  I  am  not  asking  for  too  much) please ?  I  cannot  understand  anything.  @Omnomnomnom

Comment: See my latest edit