# $f\circ g$ continuous, what does it imply on $f$,$g$?

Tags: continuity, function-and-relation-composition

Let $X,Y,Z$ be metric spaces. Let $g:X\to Y$ and $f:Y \to Z$ two applications such that $f$ is continuous and $f\circ g$ is also continuous. Do we necessary have $g$ continuous ?

Is it possible to construct an example such that $f\circ g$ is continuous while $f$ or $g$ is not ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424596/relation-between-continuity-of-f-g-and-f-circ-g?rq=1 might help

Comment: If f(x) = k then f(g(x)) would be continuous when g is not.  There are certainly less severe examples.  If f = g^{-1} then both could be discontinuous yet the composition be continuous.

Comment: What if f (x)= k a constant function.  Then g (x) can be anything.  Or if f (x) is injective with f (a)=f (b) and lim(x- > z) g (x)=a but g (z) = b then f(g ()) is continuous but g isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f (a)=f (b) ;a\ne b $.

Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow z} g (x)=a $ but $g (x) = b $.  Then $g$ is not continuous at $z $.  Then as $f $ is continuous $\lim_{x\rightarrow z} f (g (x)) = f (\lim g (x))=f (a)=f (b)=f (g (z)) $.  So $f\circ g $ is continuous at $z$.

===

Even simpler is $g $ be any discontinuous function and $f$ be any constant function.  But I wanted a non trivial example.

===

If we add the restriction $f $ is injective, I believe this becomes true.  I'm pretty sure.  Someone may want to verify that.

Comment: Definitely true for injective f.  Find discontinuity on g at z.  All d (g(x),g (z)) > e in a neighbor.  For x in the neighborhood x ne z, let r = min d (f (g (x)),f (g (x))> 0.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f$ be the Dirichlet function ($f(x)=1$ if $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $0$ otherwise). This function is continuous at no point, but $f\circ f$ is constant.